# Why do we feel sleepy when we wake up

Tags: human-biology, sleep

Why do we feel sleepy, tired, and feel like we need to sleep more when we wake up? (Like, is there a special chemical in the brain that causes that?).

Are there any ways to wake up without feeling such things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/why-do-we-feel-tired-if-we-sleep-excessively?rq=1

Comment: It is not tired by sleeping excessively, the question was why do we feel sleepy when we just wake up from being asleep.

Comment: Let say you are hungry and I stop you in the middle of your lunch. With high probability... you will be still hungry %))

Comment: I don't know if anyone else experiences this, but for me I always wake up six hours after falling asleep (and that's usually as soon as my head touches the pillow). At that precise moment when I wake up, I'm wide awake. Any sooner I feel sleepy and any later I feel groggy.

Comment: It is true I feel more sleepy in a vacation morning when I'd slept early, (with no factor of anxiety or stress) and normally rise on morning; than the end of an extremely busy, anxious, unslept night.

Comment: Probably it is not solely due to lack of sleep

Comment: maybe the brain stays in a state of "inertia" that take time to become fully alert.